# serial vs ros-noetic-rosserial

Tags: serial, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the different between these two serial packages?

- official ros: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial
- wjwwood: https://github.com/wjwwood/serial

Why is the one from wjwwood so popular? Under what circumstances would one prefer wjwwood's package over the official ROS package? Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393254/serial-vs-ros-noetic-rosserial/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2021-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These two packages serve different goals, and cannot really be compared.

From [wiki/rosserial](https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial):

> [rosserial](https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) is a [protocol](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Protocol) for wrapping standard ROS serialized messages and multiplexing multiple topics and services over a character device such as a serial port or network socket.

From [wjwwood/serial](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/blob/33e5a31ab77011504c8e37d7e9c3b9fa4229e625/README.md):

> This is a cross-platform library for interfacing with rs-232 serial like ports written in C++. It provides a modern C++ interface with a workflow designed to look and feel like PySerial, but with the speed and control provided by C++.

so the former is an implementation of a *protocol*, while the latter is a C++ library which intends to make using serial ports easier.

`rosserial` makes it possible for resource constraint environments (fi: micro controllers) to communicate with a regular ROS node graph (ie: `roscpp` / `rospy` based nodes), without having to run Linux.

`wjwwood/serial` is "simply" a serial port wrapper, it doesn't do anything but provide functions to read from and write to a serial port. *What* you read from or write to those serial ports (ie: the data) would not be something `wjwwood/serial` could help you with.

> Why is the one from wjwwood so popular?

This question only makes sense if you consider the use-cases.

If you'd like to be able to have your Arduino "talk ROS" (for example), `wjwwood/serial` wouldn't really help much.

If you'd like to be able to read and write arbitrary binary data from/to a serial port, `rosserial` wouldn't really help much.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-12-30**:
thx a lot!